# Recommended XNA tutorials to start to learn 3D (for the first time)

Tags: c#, .net, 3d, xna

I have learned a good deal of XNA in 2D and have created a good number of the classic games using XNA (Breakout, pong, a platformer, tetris) and feel quite confident about using it. I managed this using guesswork and Microsoft's meager 2D XNA tutorials.

However, now I want to begin to learn how to code games in 3D and it seems there is much, much more to learn; I have not coded in 3D before (except a failed attempt to learn the old "Managed DirectX" a few years ago) so will probably need to learn a significant amount. I have found this website, http://www.ziggyware.com/ but the I cannot find or decide which tutorial to start on (something tells me I shouldn't be learning to build HLSL shaders just yet...). Can you recommend any good tutorials to begin with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've always though that http://www.riemers.net/ has great tutorials for XNA, especially, that some series have MDX version, so you can see the different way of doing something in XNA/MDX.

//Edit:
Aso for the HLSL, nowaday everything runs on shaders, XNA gives you a basic shader that enabled you to render some basic scenes, but learning hlsl and writing own shaders is the only way to achieve something better, so you shouldn't be afraid of them. Again, what I like in riemers tutorials was that introduction to shaders, rendering to textures was pretty smooth, although I had an expierience with 3D before I started using XNA, so you might have a bit different point of view.

Comment: Regarding shaders, I made some myself using these tutorials (http://digierr.spaces.live.com/?_c11_BlogPart_BlogPart=blogview&_c=BlogPart&partqs=cat%3dXNA%2520Shader%2520Tutorial ) and nvidia fx designer.

Comment: Thanks, the tutorial I am currently doing is excellent.

Answer (score 3):

A free tutorial with videos by Microsoft: http://creators.xna.com/en-US/education/gettingstarted/bg3d/chapter1

I recommend getting a copy of Learning XNA 3.0 published by O'Reilly as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really enjoying [Microsoft XNA Game Studio 3.0 Unleashed](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-XNA-Game-Studio-Unleashed/dp/0672330229). It first chapters deal with 3D. It might start out too basic for you though if you're well versed in other areas of XNA.